Integral transformation that I don't understand.
I am confused about an integral transformation used in a certain algorithm. The purpose of the algorithm was to obtain distance when accelerating/decelerating without the need to explicitly know how much time is consumed. Normally when someone wants the same thing, they would first integrate acceleration to obtain the expression of velocity, then integrate velocity w.r.t. the same interval to get the total distance, obviously needs to know the interval.
The algorithm is as follows:
Since: $s = \int{vdt}$ $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$ (1)
We also know that: $a = \frac{dv}{dt}$ $\quad\quad\quad\quad$ (2)
That is: $dt = \frac{dv}{a}$ $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$ (3)
Substituting gives us: $s = \int{\frac{v}{a}dv}$ $\quad\quad$ (4)
Now my confusion is that in (2) it's actually $a(t)=\frac{dv(t)}{dt}$, but for the final expression to make sense it should be $s = \int{\frac{v}{a(v)}dv}$, which means during the substitution of $dt$, acceleration $a$ has changed from $a(t)$ to $a(v)$.
Questions:

Is that transformation vaild in a mathematical sense? -If not, which step or where does the bug lie?
If the transformation isn't valid in a mathematical sense, could it be possible that from an engineer's point of view it's "theoretically wrong, but works"?


While $a = \frac{dv}{dt}$ has meaning, the expression $dt  = \frac{dv}{a}$ is meaningless. It's not arithmetic with numbers. I recommend not mixing different variables.
